# how to make UISearchBar static in TableView in Iphone Application

Tags: iphone, uitableview

can anybody tell me that how should I make permanently visible the UISearch bar in TableView.
In my Application I have put search-bar on top of the table but when user scroll down search-bar disappear.

Please Help me Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making your search bar a subview of the table view, make it a subview of the table view's parent view, which is likely to be your view controller's `view` property.